# Generating C# Rest API Client from swagger.json

Tags: c#, visual-studio, swagger, nswag

I am attempting to create a Rest API Client from the Swagger json file generated by Ambari. Unfortunately the json uses # in item names:

```
  "get": {
    "tags": [ "Actions" ],
    "summary": "Get all action definitions",
    "description": "",
    "operationId": "ActionService#getActionDefinitions",       <<<<<
    "produces": [ "text/plain" ],
```

I have tried AutoRest, Nswag, Swagger and Open API Rest API Client Generators.
Nswag is the only one that does not crash and burn.
However it's output is unusable because the '#' characters end up in the c# names.

## is reserved for the compiler directives.

I end up with lines like...unusable:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ActionResponseSwagger>> ActionService#getActionDefinitionsAsync(string fields, string sortBy, int? page_size, string from, string to);
```

Is there a work around to this issue ?

Comment: You could do search-replace (using text/regex search or an OpenAPI parser) to remove `#` from operationIds in the API definition before generating the client code. Also consider opening issues with the mentioned projects to improve the handling of special characters in operationIds.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using SwaggerHub https://swagger.io/tools/swaggerhub/. It did a good job of generating a RestSharp client. Unfortunately, the Ambari Swagger json is poorly defined. You still need to edit the Requests. But at least SwaggerGen created the entire client without choking. Most of the tools I tried needed manual edits of the json.

More detailed information at:
[How to use RestSharp with Ambari Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63181329/how-to-use-restsharp-with-ambari-swagger)

Comment: Most of the definitions we generate code from require some form of pre- and/or post-processing. We use an in-house OpenAPI Code Generator utility with embedded scripting, search/replace, etc to manage this. And, as you say, the various generators have quite different behaviors and flexibility (and accuracy!).